# Getting handle of current window to GetWindowText?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to display the Title of the Dialog box:

```
HWND hWnd = ::GetActiveWindow();
char cc[101];
::GetWindowText(hWnd,cc,100);
MessageBox(cc);
```

but the result yields a blank "".

not sure what is wrong??

Comment: Seems like poor design. If a module needs to interact with a window, it should be given the handle and not have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Retrieves the window handle to the active window attached to the calling thread's message queue.

This means that if the thread which you are calling the function from doesn't own any window, the function will fail.

You probably want [`GetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may coming a bit late but anyway. If you want to get the current (active) window on the system at any time, the best approach is by using a procedure implemented in a DLL, then installing a global hook that call this procedure.

The following resources are quite helpful:

1. [Creating and using your DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)
2. [An overview on Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)